# Issue with remember me in asp mvc membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https, asp.net-membership

I have **https** website and I am using membership for logins and
my code in controller:

```
int timeout = rememberme ? 2880 : 2; // Timeout in minutes,525600 = 365 days
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, rememberme, timeout);
string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);//My Line
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

string returnurl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, rememberme);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnurl)) returnurl = "/Panel/Login";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnurl)) returnurl = "/Panel/Login";
if (rol == "User")
    return Redirect("/Panel/Dashboard");
else if (rol == "Admin")
    return Redirect("/Panel/DashboardAdmin");

return View();
```

and in we.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" executionTimeout="100000000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Panel/Login" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

so its just keep login for 2 minutes and remember me is not working 
what should I do?

Comment: I don't think this is SSL related.

Comment: \is your problem that timeout is stuck at 2?

Comment: tanks for your answer,i dont know its 2 minutes or what ever its just not working and after short time its going to log out (and i dont know it is 2 min  or more)

Comment: i think its ssl because i have an other website with http and its working fine

Comment: Do you use IIS? The cookie might become invalid after a app-pool recycle, typically after 20 minutes or so or when you restart your application.

Comment: try to check rememerme object, may be its not mapped correctly to your rememberme object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should add this to system.web in web.config file
an U can generate this key in iis but if U can access to iis U can use this code

```
    <machineKey
  decryptionKey="1513F567EE75F7FB5AC0AC4D79E1D9F25430E3E2F1BCDD3370BCFC4EFC97A541"
  validationKey="32CBA563F26041EE5B5FE9581076C40618DCC1218F5F447634EDE8624508A129"
  decryption="AES"
  validation="SHA1"
  />
```